# GAE Full Text Search development console UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an index with manny words with accent (e.g: São Paulo, José, etc).
The search api works fine, but when try to do some test queries on development console, I can't access index data.
This error only occurs on development environment. On production GAE everything works fine.

Bellow the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 701, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/admin/__init__.py", line 1704, in get
    'values': self._ProcessSearchResponse(resp),
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/admin/__init__.py", line 1664, in _ProcessSearchResponse
    value = TruncateValue(doc.fields[field_name].value)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/admin/__init__.py", line 158, in TruncateValue
    value = str(value)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc1' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: I think this is more appropriate for http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Comment: It was fixed in 1.7.0, see http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes

Comment: Yes, updating to 1.7.0 everything works fine.