# python appengine unicodeencodeerror on search api snippeted results

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-search-api

I'm crawling pages and indexing them with appengine search api (Spanish and Catalan pages, with accented characters). I'm able to perform searches and make a page of results.

Problem arises when I try to use a query object with snipetted_fields, as it always generates a UnicodeEncodeError:

```
  File "/home/otger/python/jobs-gae/src/apps/search/handlers/results.py", line 82, in find_documents
    return index.search(query_obj)
  File "/opt/google_appengine_1.7.6/google/appengine/api/search/search.py", line 2707, in search
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('search', 'Search', request, response)
  File "/opt/google_appengine_1.7.6/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/opt/google_appengine_1.7.6/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 320, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/opt/google_appengine_1.7.6/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/opt/google_appengine_1.7.6/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/opt/google_appengine_1.7.6/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 234, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    raise pickle.loads(response_pb.exception())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 52: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've found a similar question on stackoverflow: [GAE Full Text Search development console UnicodeEncodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471398/gae-full-text-search-development-console-unicodeencodeerror) but it says that it was a bug fixed on 1.7.0. I get same error either using version 1.7.5 and 1.7.6.

When Indexing pages I add two fields: description and description_ascii. If I try to generate snippets for description_ascii it works perfectly.

Is this possible to generate snippets of not ascii contents on dev_appserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug, reported new defect issue https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9335.

Temporary solution for dev server - locate google.appengine.api.search module (search.py), and patch function _DecodeUTF8 by adding inline if like this:

```
def _DecodeUTF8(pb_value):
  """Decodes a UTF-8 encoded string into unicode."""
  if pb_value is not None:
    return pb_value.decode('utf-8') if not isinstance(pb_value, unicode) else pb_value
  return None
```

Workaround - until the issue is solved implement *snippet* functionality yourself - assuming field which is base for snippet is called `snippet_base`:

```
query = search.Query(query_string=query_string,
                 options=
                    search.QueryOptions(
                        ...
                        returned_fields= [... 'snippet_base' ...]
                        ))
results = search.Index(name="<index-name>").search(query)
if results:
    for res in results.results:
        res.snippet = some_snippeting_function(res.field("snippet_base"))
```